# How to redirect traffic throught tunnel with Firehol utility?

Tags: linux, proxy, routing, redirect

**Special for pQd: please, don't change title again. I need to know, how configure Firehol utility on host 1, not firewall 2. And thank you for your reply. I am studying openvpn now.**

There is next topology:

1. Standalone linux with one eth0.
2. Cisco 2800 series router with opened 555 port.
3. linux in LAN receiving the incoming traffic.

I need to redirect trafic from host 1 to host 3 throught router 2.

Which simple service can tunnel traffic in my situation?

And how I shuld configure Firehol to redirect to tunnel?

Comment: "Cisco" is a company who makes hundreds (thousands maybe?) of different products. Which one might you be referring to in #2?

Comment: @ErikA, i fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [openvpn](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source.html) between both linux boxes. it can use single tcp or udp port [you decide which number - it can be 555 ] to tunnel any type of ip traffic between the hosts.

you can also try to use just [ssh to tunnel the traffic](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=ssh%20traffic%20tunneling%20tutorial).